# Unique ID of a snakemake run

Tags: bioinformatics, snakemake

When running a Nextflow pipeline, a unique ID is associated with the whole run. It can, for example, be obtained by examining the `nextflow log`. I am looking for the same feature for Snakemake pipelines. How do I obtain such a unique ID for a complete Snakemake pipeline run?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

When you run a pipeline, snakemake creates a log file in `/path/to/working_dir/.snakemake/log` named with the current time and process id (I think it's a process id, but it doesn't matter). Eg.: `output/.snakemake/log/2023-09-11T172850.914729.snakemake.log`. I guess the name of this file could be taken as run id. Perhaps explaining why you need a run id could prompt better answers.

Comment: I am trying to track the execution of Snakemake pipeline runs. I expect every Snakemake pipeline run to have a unique ID that I can associate it with.